# yarn add not working

Tags: yarnpkg, mdc-components

I can't install a forked git repository. I want to install version #0.31.0.

```
yarn add https://github.com/Goldjan/material-components-web.git#v0.31.0
```

I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\qjan8\Websites\XXXXXX>yarn add https://github.com/Goldjan/material-components-web.git#v0.31.0
yarn add v1.7.0
[1/4] Resolving packages...
error Can't add undefined: invalid package version undefined.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.
```

Does this have to be a name for the `package.json`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a similar issue, the repo I was trying to add as a dependency didn't have a `version` field in the `package.json`. Adding that fixed the issue.